# How do you parse a webpage after all of data loads?

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I am working on a simple website that will parse the information from the tables in the url I pass to simple_html_dom. The table on the webpage initially initializes with all zeros, so when I parse it I just get all zeros. Is there anyway to parse after everything has loading. By the way I am using PHP. Here is an example of how I parse one of the data fields.

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html =  file_get_html('http://games.espn.go.com/fba/standings?leagueId=169400&seasonId=2014');

$fg_pcts = array();

foreach($html->find('td') as $element) {
    if ($element->class == 'precise sortableStat19') {
        array_push($fg_pcts, $element->plaintext);
    }
}
```

Here is what the table looks like:
[fantasy table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkUhz.jpg)

Comment: If data is loaded via JavaScript client-side, then you can not get this data by just requesting the original HTML with PHP – you would need a client that also retrieves and executes this JS code first.

Comment: you have to check the source codes in target site and analyze java scripts in that site. Certainly you can find other url that loads variables in table. Then you can use new url to parse information directly by php.

Comment: have you considered asking the site host if they have an api for data access?